# Imacros: How to extract specific date from table?

Tags: csv, imacros

```
URL GOTO=https://chinesepod.com/tools/glossary/entry/ugly
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Download&&HREF:* EXTRACT=HREF

TAG POS=2 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Download&&HREF:* EXTRACT=HREF

TAG POS=3 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=3 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Download&&HREF:* EXTRACT=HREF

SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=E:\ FILE=pinyin.csv
```

I use this code to extract text and URL but it always extract wrong URL. 
I explained more detail here:

[image]

So the text doesn't match the URL. How to fix it?

Comment: Please explain it in more detail over here too if future readers have the same problem and the image gets deleted.

Comment: Did you try to increase the position numbers by 1 in your lines with `TAG POS=n TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Download&&HREF:* EXTRACT=HREF`?

Answer (score 1):

**@Shugar is right, you just need to modify the position number by one in your file.**

Example below:

```
URL GOTO=https://chinesepod.com/tools/glossary/entry/ugly

' Extract "It's really ugly"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Download&&HREF:* EXTRACT=HREF

' Extract "This cat is really ugly"
TAG POS=2 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=3 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Download&&HREF:* EXTRACT=HREF

' Extract "Thanks. You're really ugly!"
TAG POS=3 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=4 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Download&&HREF:* EXTRACT=HREF
```

**Alternatively, you can use Relative positioning** to find the mp3 url of the sentence, as it's the first download link after the sentence via using POS=R#  (where # is integer, can be negative too like POS=R-3).

```
URL GOTO=https://chinesepod.com/tools/glossary/entry/ugly

' Extract "It's really ugly"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Download&&HREF:* EXTRACT=HREF

' Extract "This cat is really ugly"
TAG POS=2 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Download&&HREF:* EXTRACT=HREF

' Extract "Thanks. You're really ugly!"
TAG POS=3 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Download&&HREF:* EXTRACT=HREF
```